# Python runs program once but won't run again

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm new here but I've been searching around the internet for a few days and can't find anything to figure this out. So I have a very basic program (Code at bottom) and if it's the first time in 10+ hrs, it'll run just fine and do what it's supposed to do (basically nothing at this point). But if I exit the window and try to run it again, it'll give a "Python has stopped working" error message.

python 3.6.1 and kivy 1.10.0 (but this program doesn

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

TestApp().run()
```

Any advice or help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: How exactly are you exiting the window? What platform are you on?

Comment: After you exit is the process still running? It seems to work for me.

Comment: Im on Windows 10. Im just clicking the exit button like on any other window...is there a better way to kill the program? And I've looked in task manager and I can't find the program

Comment: And other scripts still work fine

Answer (score 0):

What is your output of this code?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
def exit(self):
    App.get_running_app().stop()
btn1 = Button(text='Hello world 1')
btn1.bind(on_press= exit)

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return btn1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

This is how you can exit your app with a button.

You should find your programm in the taskmanager called "Python" and has the same icon as displayed in your taskbar.

How do you run your code ? (in pycharm or in terminal?)

I hope I could help.

Comment: It does the same thing. Shows the window with "hello world 1" and when I click it, it exits. But if I try to run it again, python crashes. I've been running it by double clicking the program.py file on my desktop. I just tried running it in pyton and it says it finished with exit code -1073740771 (0xC000041D)

Comment: maybe you have to reinstall python or/and kivy